# delete previous photo in updating profile photo in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, upload, photo

How can I delete the previous photos while uploading new one?

here's my update avatar function

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::User();

    $avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.'.'.request()->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $request->avatar->storeAs('avatars',$avatarName);

    $user->avatar = $avatarName;
    $user->save();

    return back()
        ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');
}
```

EDIT:

I am storing the photos on STORAGE > APP > PUBLIC >AVATARS

What this code does, it only override the previous photo. for example i have my current `2_avartar.jpg`, if I update my photo with PNG extension file, the `2_avartar.jpg` will still be remain while `2_avartar.jpg.png` is added. And if I update again GIF file both `2_avartar.jpg` and `2_avartar.png` will be remain and new `2_avartar.gif` will be added. There's no problem if you upload same extension name with what you have before updating the photo. The solution I am looking for is something like delete all 2_avatar.* before adding the new photo.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you're the friend who suggested this to me yesterday please post it again.
it was my mistake I did not check the folder name.

```
    $folder = 'avatar';
    Storage::delete($folder.'/'.$user->avatar);
```

again answer is not mine it was answered yesterday which have been deleted because I thought it's not working.

Comment: Why doesn’t that work? That should work surely if it already knows the file name?

Comment: ahhh i can see now. the $folder value supposed to be 'avatars' . please if you are the friend who suggested this answer yesterday,     $folder = 'avatar';
    Storage::delete($folder.'/'.$user->avatar); post again your question. it was my mistake. I haven't check the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request)
{
    $folder = 'avatars';

    $request->validate([
        'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::User();

    if ($user->avatar) {
        Storage::delete($folder . '/' . $user->avatar);
        $user->avatar = null;
        $user->save();
    }

    $avatarName = $user->id . '_avatar' . '.'
     . request()->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $request->avatar->storeAs($folder, $avatarName);

    $user->avatar = $avatarName;
    $user->save();

    return back()
        ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');
}
```

NB The reason for saving the user twice is incase there’s a problem storing the file, so that the user is not left with a link to a deleted image as their avatar.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to unlink it from your public folder where you have stored it.

```
 unlink(public_path('/images/profilepics/'.$sortImageName));
```